# Refresh POP Accounts

Tags: gmail, pop3

In my Gmail account, I use "[Refresh POP accounts](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2010/03/new-in-labs-refresh-pop-accounts.html)" by Emmanuel P to add a simple button at the top of my email list to quickly refresh all the POP email accounts I have attached to my Gmail account.

I cannot, for the life of me, find a method to do this on my LG Optimus. Is something like this available for Android?

## Update

I use the official Google Gmail app. Gmail automatically checks pop accounts, but does not check the accounts on a regular schedule. The POP accounts can be checked manually via "Refresh POP accounts" Labs plugin in desktop browswers. However, this is not available in the Gmail app or in mobile browsers.

Comment: Not an answer but if you use Gmail app, you don't have to bother with this.

Comment: I do use the Gmail app. You may want to read about Gmail and POP accounts. Gmail automatically checks pop accounts, but does not check the accounts on a regular schedule. The POP accounts can be checked manually via "Refresh POP accounts" Labs plugin ins desktop browswers. However, this is not available in the Gmail app or in mobile browsers. - Added to Question edit.

Comment: I have some bad news for you. You may not wish to hear this, but it looks as if it is not possible. Or, at least it is not possible until google make it possible. Sorry about this!

Comment: I am also pretty sure that Google won't provide a solution: To check mails on a POP account you have to *pull them*, and that's what every service provider wants to avoid in terms of resource consumption.

Comment: have you considered using an alternative email client like K-9 for both your GMail as well as your POP3 mailbox?

Comment: No interest. I am happy with Gmail as my client. I simply want to be able to check the POP accounts from my Android phone the same way I can from Gmail in a desktop browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could give [POP3 Refresh for Gmail](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.greatbytes.pop3refresh) app a try. It sounds like it does what you are looking for.

Comment: That looks perfect. Being it was just released today, I think I will wait a few days to check out the feedback. Yes, I realize it is only $1.29, but I don't buy Andriod apps unless they have fantastic user feedback.

Comment: Great support as well! There was a bug and it was fixed promptly!

Answer (score 0):

Using the desktop vesion of gmail works, even though it's a bit clumsy. Here's how to access it:

- open Chrome, go to gmail.com
- click "go to the mobile Gmail site"
- open Chrome's options menu (3 vertical dots), tick "Request desktop site"
- roll out the hamburger menu in gmail (button with 3 stripes), scroll down and click "View Gmail in: **Desktop**"
- switch to the "standard" Gmail view instead of "basic HTML" (at the bottom right)
- you should now see the standard gmail app, which has a refresh button
  [image: refresh button]
- click it and wait for a bit, your POP3/IMAP emails should be fetched

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to a standalone app, I’ve just added this link to my home screen, after saving my Gmail credentials, and click the “Check mail now” link next to the account to do the POP3 refresh.

`https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?ui=2&fs=1&view=pu&st=labs#settings/accounts`